# How do I get my canvas animation to play/stop when the play/pause button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, function, animation, canvas, onclick

How do I get my canvas animation of the rain to start when the play button is clicked and vice versa (stop the rain when the pause button is clicked)?

I really would appreciate a helping hand.

So far I have the rain animation to play as soon as the window is loaded and the audio in the background is the only thing that plays when interacting with the play button.

I'm not sure how to go about getting the rain animation to start so that the audio also plays in sync with the rain and vice versa.

```js
// Get the canvas and context and store in variables
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

// Set canvas dimensions to window height and width 
canvas.width = window.innerHeight;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

// Generate the raindrops and apply attributes 
var rainNum = 200; // max raindrops 
var rainDrops = [];

let isClicked = true;

// Loop through the empty raindrops and apply attributes
for (var i = 0; i < rainNum; i++) {
  rainDrops.push({
    x: Math.random() * canvas.width,
    y: Math.random() * canvas.height,
  })
}

// Draw raindrops onto canvas 
function draw() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  context.lineWidth = 0.1;
  context.strokeStyle = "white";
  context.beginPath();

  for (var i = 0; i < rainNum; i++) {
    var r = rainDrops[i];
    context.moveTo(r.x, r.y);
    context.lineTo(r.x, r.y + 30);
    rainDrops[i].y += 13;
    context.stroke();
  }
  if (isClicked == true) {
    moveRain();
  } else {
    return false
  }

  window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);

}

window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);

// Animate the raindrops
function moveRain() {

  for (var i = 0; i < rainNum; i++) {
    // Store current raindrops
    var r = rainDrops[i];

    // If the rain reaches the bottom, send a new one to the top
    if (r.y > canvas.height) {
      rainDrops[i] = {
        x: Math.random() * canvas.width,
        y: 0
      };
    }
  }

}

// Create a reference to the audio
var audioOne = document.querySelector("#audio-1");

function playAudio() {

  if (isClicked == true) {
    isClicked = false
    audioOne.pause();
    btn.className = "play";
  } else if (isClicked == false) {
    isClicked = true
    audioOne.play();
    btn.className = "pause";
    draw()
  }
}
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
}

#sky-top {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  animation: lightning 20s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@keyframes lightning {
  /****** This will create a lightning effect every 20 seconds ******/
  0% {
    background-color: rgb(46, 46, 46);
  }
  6.25% {
    background-color: rgb(46, 46, 46);
  }
  8% {
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  }
  9% {
    background-color: rgb(46, 46, 46);
  }
  11% {
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  }
  30% {
    background-color: rgb(46, 46, 46);
  }
  100% {
    background-color: rgb(46, 46, 46);
  }
}

#sky-bottom {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgb(45, 45, 45));
}

.center-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 20;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.button-center {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.center-container:after,
.button-center {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#btn {
  height: 130px;
  width: 130px;
  border: none;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  outline: none;
}

.play {
  background: url('../image/play-button.png');
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(2px 2px 2px #666666);
  filter: drop-shadow(2px 2px 2px #666666);
}

.pause {
  background: url('../image/pause-button.png');
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(2px 2px 2px #666666);
  filter: drop-shadow(2px 2px 2px #666666);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <title>Rain</title>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta name="description" content="Relax your mind with some rain and thunder.">
  <link href="css/styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>

  <div id="sky-top"></div>
  <div id="sky-bottom"></div>
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>

  <div class="center-container">

    <div class="button-center">
      <button id="btn" class="play" class="pause" onclick="playAudio()"></button>
    </div>

    <audio src="audio/rain-and-thunder.mp3" id="audio-1" loop="loop" type="audio/mp3"></audio>

  </div>

  <script src="js/script.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, the audio file won't work for me here locally (I downloaded my own mp3 - I am working on getting it to work now), so I focused on playing/pausing the canvas animation and ignored the sound functionality.  Let's start with the HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel = "stylesheet"
   type = "text/css"
   href = "index.css" />
</head>
<body>
              <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>

        <div class="center-container">
            
            <div class="button-center">
                <button id="btn" class="play" class="pause" onclick="playAudio()"></button>
            </div>

            <audio loop="loop" id="audio-1" width="100%" height="auto">
              <source src="audio/rain-and-thunder.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
              </audio>
        
        </div>
</body>
<script src='index.js'></script>
</html>
```

You'll see I did a few things to display the `canvas` properly.  For whatever reason, I couldn't see your button and the canvas was showing up blank.  I decided to `inline CSS` the `width` and `height`, as well as put the script within the `body`.

Also, since we are ignoring the sound functionality, I renamed the function to `startStopRain()` to make more sense in your JS file.  Let's talk about that next:

```
// Get the canvas and context and store in variables
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var audioOne = document.getElementById("audio-1");

// Set canvas dimensions to window height and width 
canvas.width = window.innerHeight;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

// Generate the raindrops and apply attributes 
var rainNum = 200; // max raindrops 
var rainDrops = [];

let isClicked = false

// Loop through the empty raindrops and apply attributes
for(var i = 0; i < rainNum; i ++)
{
    rainDrops.push({
        x: Math.random() * canvas.width,
        y: Math.random() * canvas.height,
    })
}

// Draw raindrops onto canvas 
function draw()
{   
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    context.lineWidth = 0.1;
    context.strokeStyle = "red";
    context.beginPath(); 

    for(var i = 0; i < rainNum; i ++)
    {
        var r = rainDrops[i];
        context.moveTo(r.x, r.y);
        context.lineTo(r.x, r.y + 30);
        rainDrops[i].y += 13;
        context.stroke();
    }
    if (isClicked == true) {
        moveRain();
    } else{
        return false
    }

    document.getElementById("canvas").onclick = moveRain();

    window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}


window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);

// Animate the raindrops
function moveRain(){
    for(var i = 0; i < rainNum; i++)
        {
        // Store current raindrops
        var r = rainDrops[i];

        // If the rain reaches the bottom, send a new one to the top
        if(r.y > canvas.height) {
            rainDrops[i] = {x: Math.random() * canvas.width, y: 0};
        }
    }
}

// Create a reference to the audio


// need to figure out why the audio wont play - this is new to me :D
function playAudio(){
    audioOne.play();
    if (isClicked == true){
        isClicked = false
        audioOne.pause();
    } else if (isClicked == false){
        isClicked = true
        audioOne.play();
        draw()
    }
}
```

Your original intent was to use two class names on the `btn` so you could distinguish between play/pause.  While there are use cases for using multiple class names, I don't personally believe this is one of them.  Instead, I used a global `isClicked` variable in the script so I could control the flow of the functions.

Follow the `isClicked` variable from top to bottom to better understand how I used it to call/stop functions.  Minus initializing the variable at the top, you'll notice it shows up in only two functions: `draw()` and `startStopRain()`.

EDIT:  The flow control for the sound should be no different.  You can use the same `isClicked` `boolean` value to determine when the sound should be played or not.  If you want, I can update it to reflect that but truthfully, that would be good practice for you.  Also, I changed the `id` of the button to `audio-1` since the original code was selecting the element via that specific `id`

Comment: my play and pause buttons are actually white png images of the symbol! and thank you!! I got the rain animation to work when the play/pause button is pressed and also in sync with the audio :) But I'm not sure why it's letting me click twice for the audio to start, and the play button ( > arrow image) switches to the pause button at the second click as well :(

Comment: I added audioOne.pause()  &  btn.className = "play" under if(isClicked == true) and i added audioOne.play() " &  "  btn.className = "pause" underelse if(isClicked == false)

Comment: Hey Sue, glad my logic got you on the right path!  I can look at it more today when I find sometime.  If I helped, it'd be great if you accepted the answer.  Thanks!

Comment: Hey sue, I am not sure whether you want the rain/sound in motion when the page loads or not.  In my EDITED code above, you'll see that everything is paused until you click the button.  When you click the button ONCE, they'll both start together.  Check it out.

Comment: Hey I accepted your answer! I really appreciate you trying to help me out :) I don't want the rain already in motion when page is loaded, I would like the rain to start falling from the top when I press play and freeze when I click the pause button. Basically, I only have one button at the centre of the page to control the rain animation. When the page loads, it will default to the play button and once button is clicked, it will change to the pause button.

Comment: (cont').. What's happening right now is that the rain is already in motion when the page loads. After I click play once, the rain freezes & the play button is still there. When I click twice, that's when the rain animation is in sync with the play/stop button– the rain falls, changing to the pause button, and audio plays which is what i want at first click.

Comment: Check out my edited code!  The HTML may be slightly different than yours, so look into it as well.

Comment: Thank you but it still the same :( I would need to click twice to get the rain animation and the button to be in sync with each other.

Comment: Hmm... that's odd.  Mines completely paused until I click once?  I'm only use on button and I don't have the PNG files for the button like you do?  We have a disconnect somewhere.

Comment: Truthfully, it'd help to repost (through an edit) your existing code again just to see what changes have been made.

Comment: I appreciate you continuously trying to help me :')... I just updated my code on this post! I ran the snippet and it looks awfully weird. That's not how it appears on the actual page. Also the button doesn't appear because i cannot add images here so you would have to mouse over the centre to click. On the snippet it seems to work just fine but on my page it certainly runs differently with the button, rain animation, and audio out of sync.

Comment: That's really odd... so the logic works fine in the snippet (and it works fine on my end as well when I run it in my local environment) but it's not working in your "live" version.  Send over the URL!